# Parsing XML results in SAXParseException with Unexpected End of Document

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am running into a strange error with trying to parse XML from an android device. What is strange is parsing the xml worked several days before and I have not touched the code. Today, loading the xml will not work.

The xml files are located in the "assets" folder in my project directory.

Here is the part where I am passing the path of that specific xml file into a parser called `MazeFileReader`.

```
private void generateFromFile() {
    Log.v(TAG, "Generating from file");
    File maze_file = new File(getCacheDir() + "/" + pregen_maze);
      if (!maze_file.exists()) try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open(pregen_maze);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(maze_file);
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.close();
      } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }

      MazeFileReader mazeFileReader = new MazeFileReader(getApplicationContext(), maze_file.getPath());
```

Here is `MazeFileReader` now taking that path and trying to parse it.

```
private void load(String filename)
{
    try{

        File fXmlFile = new File(filename);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile); //Fails here
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Maze");

        for (int temp = 0 ; temp < nList.getLength() ; temp++) {

            ...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
```

I've traced the error and it seems in that this line of code executes in `DocumentBuilderImpl`

```
if (parser.nextToken() == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            throw new SAXParseException("Unexpected end of document", null);
}
```

Also, I don't think there is anything wrong with my xml file either as I have not touched it and it was working several days before. I have 4 or 5 other xml files that have all worked, but today, all run into the same `SAXParseException` for some reason. What are the possible reasons for `SAXParseException`? Is it possible that the filepath to the xml is incorrect?

Here is the xml in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Maze>

    <sizeX>
4
    </sizeX>

    <sizeY>
4
    </sizeY>

    <roomNum>
0
    </roomNum>

    <partiters>
60
    </partiters>

    <cell_0>
173
    </cell_0>

    <cell_1>
132
    </cell_1>

    <cell_2>
140
    </cell_2>

    <cell_3>
198
    </cell_3>
</Maze>
```

EDIT: I found something WEIRD. I checked out an old version of my project and it still does not work. Then I made a new emulator and reinstalled the app. Now it works!!! What is the reason behind this?

I've discovered something else. The xml file will run into `SAXParserException` if I debug and step through the parsing. Then the file will be unable to parse from then on. However, if I do not debug it and reinstall the app on a new device, then the xml parses correctly. Btw, the xml is located in `assets` folder. Why is Android exhibiting this sort of behavior?. Are the xml files somehow getting corrupted?

Comment: That exception means the file is empty or damaged (truncated).

Comment: Make sure there is no problem with the "filename" first.

Comment: @Leog I don't think there is a problem with the filename. The filename is exactly what I'd expect. I think if the file did not exist, it would probably throw a different kind of error.